# Cannot access Https website hosted on aws with s3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a website hosted on AWS s3. The website is working fine on HTTP. Since I needed SSL on my website, I tried to set up a CloudFront distribution with SSL from ACM. The CloudFront link that I get after the distribution setup shows HTTPS which proves that the SSL is attached to the distribution. But when I try to access the website, it only works on HTTP and not on HTTPS. I have set up an A record in route 53 to the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Do you have your own domain name or just using the CloudFront distribution domain?

If you have your own domain name, make sure to add your domain name to `Alternate Domain Names
(CNAMEs)` in your CloudFront distribution settings

Comment: Yes @iTech i have already added the alternate domains in cloudFront and also hav SSL for the domain